# When I create an object from a class that extends a specific interface, can I use this object in the place where I use this interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, implements

I know that I can pass an `interface` as an argument. Since we cannot create an object from an `interface`! Can I create an object from a `class` that `extends` this `interface` then I use this object in the place where I use this `interface` as an argument?

My question, since `obj` is an object from `Final` class, can I use it as a parameter here (`m1(obj)`)? And explain to me why, please?

```
package aaa;

public class AAA {
    public static void m1(One one) {
      System.out.print("AAA");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Final obj = new Final();
      m1(obj);
    }
}

interface One {
}

class Final  implements One {
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that you actually **can** create object from interface, it's called Anonymous Class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.
Interfaces are a way in Java to avoid multiple inheritance, i.e. declaring a class `Foo` to extend a class `Bar` and implement an interface `Bar` means that we have a "is a" relationship between `Foo` and `Bar`/`Baz`. So, "`Foo` is a `Bar`" and "`Foo` is a `Baz`" are true or in your case `Final` is a `One`. So, if a type is a subtype (or in Java implements an interface) the subtype can be used in place of the type or the interface (see the Liskov  substitution principle).

When you declare a method `m1(One one)`, you require the first parameter to be of type `One` and as `Final` is a `One` this is obviously true.

Please note, that even though you pass in an object of type `Final` the method only "sees" the interface part of the object without casting it.